# Transaction is getting rolledback while persisting objects in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have following code to persist data in Oracle.

```
    Language lang = new Language();
    lang.setLangCode("06");
    lang.setLanguage("german");

    Data dc = new Data();
    dc.setDescription("description_german");
    dc.setName("name_german");
    dc.setLanguage(lang);

    //2.
    Language lang2 = new Language();
    lang2.setLangCode("06");
    lang2.setLanguage("german");

    Document doc  = new Document();
    doc.setDescription("description_de");
    doc.setName("name_de");


    doc.setLanguage(lang2); // When I do like: doc.setLanguage(lang) it persists the data
    doc.setDataCollection(dc);
    em.merge(doc);
```

When I run the above code it give me transaction rollback following are the logs

```
TRACE org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction - Adding resolved non-early insert action.
09-02-2018 15:14:54.273 TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade - Processing cascade ACTION_MERGE for: com.fis.cdpr.model.DataCollection
09-02-2018 15:14:54.273 TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade - Done processing cascade ACTION_MERGE for: com.fis.cdpr.model.DataCollection
09-02-2018 15:14:54.273 TRACE org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction.cascade - Cascading to merge: com.fis.cdpr.model.Language
09-02-2018 15:14:54.274 TRACE org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached - Merging detached instance
09-02-2018 15:14:54.274 TRACE org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad - Loading entity: [com.fis.cdpr.model.Language#06]
09-02-2018 15:14:54.274 TRACE org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad - Attempting to resolve: [com.fis.cdpr.model.Language#06]
09-02-2018 15:14:54.274 TRACE org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad - Resolved object in session cache: [com.fis.cdpr.model.Language#06]
09-02-2018 15:14:54.274 DEBUG org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.markForRollbackOnly - Mark transaction for rollback
```

I have overriden equals and hashcode for `Language` object

Then I tried following code just o check the problem and it worked!!

```
    Language lang1 = new Language();
    lang1.setLangCode("06");

    Language lang2 = new Language();
    lang2.setLangCode("06");

    em.merge(lang1);
    em.merge(lang2);
```

See logs below:

```
09-02-2018 16:59:44.840 TRACE org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction - Adding insert with no non-nullable, transient entities: [EntityInsertAction[com.fis.cdpr.model.Language#06]]
09-02-2018 16:59:44.840 TRACE org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction - Adding resolved non-early insert action.
09-02-2018 16:59:44.842 TRACE org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached - Merging detached instance
09-02-2018 16:59:44.842 TRACE org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad - Loading entity: [com.fis.cdpr.model.Language#06]
09-02-2018 16:59:44.843 TRACE org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad - Attempting to resolve: [com.fis.cdpr.model.Language#06]
09-02-2018 16:59:44.843 TRACE org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad - Resolved object in session cache: [com.fis.cdpr.model.Language#06]
09-02-2018 16:59:44.847 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit - committing
```

I need to understand why hibernate after looking Language object from cache is not able to persist same language object( diff reference ) but able to persist same object reference and also different language objects

I have provided relation on both `Data` and `Document` entites with `Language` as below

```
@ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "language_fk")
private Language language;
```

Update=> exception says

```
exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity [spring.model.Language#06] are being merged. Detached: [spring.model.Language@b588a401]; Detached: [spring.model.Language@b588a401]]
```

Document class

```
 @Entity
    public class Document {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="doc_name", nullable=true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn
    private Language lang;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn
    private Data data;


    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Language getLang() {
        return lang;
    }

    public void setLang(Language lang) {
        this.lang = lang;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        result = prime * result + ((lang == null) ? 0 : lang.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Document other = (Document) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (lang == null) {
            if (other.lang != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!lang.equals(other.lang))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Data Class

```
@Entity
public class Data {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="doc_name", nullable=true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="doc_fk")
    private Document doc;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn
    private Language lang;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Document getDoc() {
        return doc;
    }

    public void setDoc(Document doc) {
        this.doc = doc;
    }

    public Language getLang() {
        return lang;
    }

    public void setLang(Language lang) {
        this.lang = lang;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        result = prime * result + ((lang == null) ? 0 : lang.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Data other = (Data) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (lang == null) {
            if (other.lang != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!lang.equals(other.lang))
            return false;
        return true;
    }



}



        }
```

Language class

```
@Entity
public class Language {

    @Id
    private String langCode;

    private String language;


    public String getLangCode() {
        return langCode;
    }
    public void setLangCode(String langCode) {
        this.langCode = langCode;
    }
    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }
    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((langCode == null) ? 0 : langCode.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((language == null) ? 0 : language.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Language other = (Language) obj;
        if (langCode == null) {
            if (other.langCode != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!langCode.equals(other.langCode))
            return false;
        if (language == null) {
            if (other.language != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!language.equals(other.language))
            return false;
        return true;
    }


}
```

From the exception and when I executed em.merge(lang); em.merge(lang2) I believe it worked because there are two seperate calls to persist/merge the data thats why I never got exception while doing so. But otherwise it gives exception. Isn't hibernate suppose to merge objects when it finds one same object in Session. ?

Comment: Can you please show the code of the class Language

Comment: What's the final resulting exception?

Comment: Can you also please include the code of Data collection class and it's mapping inside Data ... Is there any direct mapping between language and data collection

Comment: because you are trying to merge detached instance of language entity

Comment: then what will be the proper code ? I believed that detached entites are those which we donot persist either by using entity manager or by session. But  in my case I am trying to persist both